# Sorting a text file

Tags: c++, string, sorting

what would be the most efficient way to sort a file with millions of string inside it?

I know how to do this, if it were a file with millions if Integers in it.

how to modify our approach if it is string?
or any new approach?

Comment: "I think the bubble sort would be the wrong way to go." - [Barrack Obama, 2008](http://www.quora.com/How-does-Obama-know-about-bubble-sort).

Comment: What character encoding are you thinking of?

Comment: @cheers: may be we can use hash value of string?

Comment: @Guru: it's just that sorting is very dependent on the encoding. Without such information, and info about the intended execution platform, there is no good answer.

Comment: As far as I understood I told you to encode it like keeping a hash value.
if anyother encoding can be helpful,please suggest

Comment: @Guru: "keeping a hash value" is not about encoding, and it's not about sorting either. Examples of common encodings include WIndows ANSI Western, ISO Latin 1, and UTF-8. What's needed for sorting these, differ.

Comment: don't know about encoding...

Comment: Read the file into a `std::set<std::string>`. Use a predicate if the sorting has special rules.

Answer (score -2):

First load all the file in memory, then use `std::sort`

You can do something like this:

```
std::fstream MyFile("MyFile.txt",ios_base::in);
std::vector<std::string>MyStrings;
while(MyFile.eof()==0){
    std::stringstream MyBuffer;
    MyBuffer<<MyFile;
    MyStrings.push_back(MyBuffer.str())
}
std::sort(MyStrings.begin(),MyStrings.end()); //no need for compare function because it exsits for std::string
```

Comment: note that since `std::string` isn't unicode aware or anything, the sorting might not be what you want so you might need to provide your own compare function

Comment: You probably shouldn't loop using `eof()`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: I think it's fine if you use it this way. I'm not reading the value when I test for the `EOF`. It is updated after reading so I guess I must misunderstand the explanation there

Comment: One problem is that you do not test if the read succeeded before using the value. Another problem is I don't understand how you are reading from `MyFile`.

Comment: Well I assume `MyFile` is a file stream since that's what you would use in C++. I should have precised that.